# Instruct composer to use different class when ambiguous

Tags: php, composer-php

When performing a composer update, I received the following warning:

> Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "Normalizer" was found in both "/var/www/concrete5/vendor/patchwork/utf8/src/Normalizer.php" and "/var/www/concrete5/vendor/voku/portable-utf8/src/Normalizer.php", the first will be used.

The site is now experiencing errors which I think might be related.

How can I instruct composer to use the second file (i.e. `/var/www/concrete5/vendor/voku/portable-utf8/src/Normalizer.php`) instead of the first?

Note that I have tried adding the following to `exclude-from-classmap` to `composer.json` and while it suppresses the warning, doesn't appear to have any impact.

```
  "autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
      "ConcreteComposer\\" : "./tests"
    },
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "vendor/patchwork/utf8/src/Normalizer.php"
    ]
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exclude-from-classmap` has effect only when classmap is used for autoloading specified class. In your case class is loaded using PSR rules, but you may use optimized autolader, which generates classmap for all classes:

```
composer install -o
```

Also, since you placed this rule inside of `autoload-dev`, it will not have effect when you run `composer install` with `--no-dev` flag.

Comment: Thanks Rob,  Oops, yep `autoload-dev` sure won't work for me.  I see how autoload_classmap.php is generated and verified that the other class was used.  Thanks